# How to toggle attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a List item where if I click on any of the list item it adds an ID "current" .

But If I click again on this list this "current" ID should removed and back to normal again, something like toggling. I am able to add the attribute but not the able to toggle. Any help will be appreciated.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oL9nt3pe/1/)

**JS**

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    $('ul li').removeAttr("id","current");
    $(this).attr("id","current");
});
```

Comment: Well if you remove it then immediately after set it back , of course it is never removed. Note also that using the id attribute is probably not the best idea... using a class would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/oL9nt3pe/5/)

Here is how to toggle:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    $('ul li').not(this).removeAttr("id");
    if( $(this).attr('id') == 'current' )
    {
        $(this).removeAttr('id');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).attr("id","current");
    }
});
```

**Use of a css class would be most recommended for work like this**:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/oL9nt3pe/6/)

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    $('ul li').not(this).removeClass("current");
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! this is accurate for me !

Answer (score 4):

It should be `$('ul li').removeAttr("id");`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oL9nt3pe/2/)**

On a related note, it's best to use classes instead of IDs for stuff like this.

Update:

To toggle, use classes like:

```
$('ul li').click(function () {
    $('ul li').not(this).removeClass("current");
    $(this).toggleClass("current");
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/25q0Lt0L/)**

Comment: Actually on my case I need Id

Comment: If you must use the ID, then you can do it this way http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/25q0Lt0L/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id") == "current"){
       $(this).removeAttr("id");
    }else{
       $(this).attr("id","current");
    }
});
```